# Stop method not getting called when terminating the windows service

Tags: java, apache, windows-services, java-8, procrun

I have converted a java application into a windows Service using procrun. When I stop the service using Windows Services program it gets hung and doesn't respond. When launch it using the debug mode and then when I terminate it using ctrl+c, I can't see the stop method being called. I have given a print statement which is not getting printed. Below is my code. Please advice. There is nothing in the Windows Even logs related to this service.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if ("start".equals(args[0])) {
        start(args);
    } else if ("stop".equals(args[0])) {
        stop(args);
    }

}

public static void start(String[] args) {

    KubeSdkMain sdkMain = new KubeSdkMain();
    sdkMain.startSDK();

}

public static void stop(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("stop");
    stop = true;

}
```

Below is the content of the bat file I run for installing the service.

```
cd "G:\Projects"
set PR_PATH="G:\Projects"
SET PR_SERVICE_NAME=TestService
SET PR_JAR=KKSDK.jar
SET START_CLASS=com.example.test
SET START_METHOD=start
SET STOP_CLASS=com.example.test
SET STOP_METHOD=stop
rem ; separated values
SET STOP_PARAMS=0
rem ; separated values
SET JVM_OPTIONS=-Dapp.home=%PR_PATH%
prunsrv.exe //IS//%PR_SERVICE_NAME% --Install="%PR_PATH%\prunsrv.exe" --Jvm=auto --Startup=auto --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=%START_CLASS% --StartMethod=%START_METHOD% --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=%STOP_CLASS% --StopMethod=%STOP_METHOD% ++StopParams=%STOP_PARAMS% --Classpath="%PR_PATH%\%PR_JAR%" --DisplayName="%PR_SERVICE_NAME%" ++JvmOptions=%JVM_OPTIONS%
```

pause

Comment: How do you initiate stop

Comment: initiate in the sense?

Comment: Do you have a thread set with `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` to call stop while debugging? Stop is explicitly set to be called in your prunsrv call, so you need to do explicitly call it during debug as well.

Comment: Your `main` method is never called twice. If you ever run your program with different arguments again (be it `stop` or something else), you will create a new process with a new JVM, not affecting the already running program.

Comment: How should I handle this situation then? please advice

Comment: @Holger: not so!  Depending on configuration, Procrun may use an in-process JVM, in which case it can call main() as often as it likes.  In this case though I think it is being configured to call start() and stop() directly.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a shutdown hook so that when you press `ctrl+c` shutdown hook gets called.

 This link might help you 
[ShutDownHook](http://www.javatpoint.com/ShutdownHook-thread)